# SQL Server: How to query date in a certain format

Tags: sql-server, date-format, date-formatting

I am pretty new to SQL and hope someone here can help me with the following:

I have a table in SQL Server with one column storing dates and I have a simple stored procedure to select data from this table.

Currently it fetches the date including hours and minutes. 
How can I achieve that it fetches the date in format yyyy-mm-dd (without the hours and minutes) ?
My column is called "logDate" and my table is called "logTable".

Thanks for any help with this, Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to store the date, convert the column to a `date` type, not a `datetime`.

If you want to keep the date and time in the data, but just display the date

```
 select convert(date, logDate) from logTable
```

If you want to return the date as a string, use `convert`

```
select convert(varchar(10), logDate, 120) from logTable
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply - i had to add "AS logDate" in the end, then your first suggestion works perfect !